Cant send back httpOnly cookie to server
So I am implementing the JWT access token / refresh token cycle. I send a refresh token in an httpOnly cookie and I want to send it back to the server.
The httpOnly cookie appears in the response 'Set-Cookie' header, but it is not visible in the Application Tab of Chrome Developer Tools(I am not sure if this is ok, some say that httpOnly cookies does not appear for security reasons).
So here is my code :
CORS OPTIONS :
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
  exposedHeaders: [
    "x-auth-token",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
  ],
};
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); 

Here is the how I send the cookie successfully to the client via the endpoint:
res
    .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    })
    .header("x-auth-token", accessToken)
    .send("User validated, token accesible from headers");

And here is the middleware I use to take back the token, but the console.log prints undefined :
module.exports = function authorizeRefreshToken(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const refreshToken = req.cookie;
    console.log("Refresh Token from client : ", refreshToken);
    if (!refreshToken) return res.status(403).send("No token inside cookie.");

    const decoded = jwt.verify(
      refreshToken,
      config.get("jwtPrivateKey"),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
            return res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send("An error with JWT occurred!");
          }
        }
      }
    );

    req._id = decoded._id;
    req.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error with the token", error);
  }
};

This is the api call in the front end :
 const getAccessToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(END_POINT, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        const token = response.headers["x-auth-token"];
        setAccessToken(token);
        console.log("Access Token in useEffect : ", token);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("AXIOS ERROR", error);
      }
    };

Here is the response i get from the server when i send the cookie to the client :
And here is the Application tab :


Actually, an httpOnly cookie does appear in the browser's Application tab but it is just not accessible. If you do something like document.cookie, all the cookies available in the Application tab would be output except the httpOnly cookies. Therefore, httpOnly cookies are only available when you make an http request to the server.
However, the reason you're not seeing the refreshToken in the browser's Application tab may be due to Samesite cookie configuration option. Cookies set with Samesite=Lax or Samesite=Strict won't be sent with your cross-site request on localhost especially if your frontend and backend are hosted on different ports-in your case http://localhost:5173 and http://localhost:3000 respectively. However, in deployment, this should work.
In order to have your refreshToken show up in the browser's Application tab in development on localhost, you should add SameSite=None to your cookie config properties.
res
    .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      secure: true, //this works only on https protocol
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      sameSite: "None"
    })
    .header("x-auth-token", accessToken)
    .send("User validated, token accesible from headers");

The reason why it is necessary to have sameSite:None property in the cookie config is because by default, if sameSite is not set, it is considered Lax. See MDN link

I changed to sameSite :'none' but it is still not visible in the Application tab.
My goal is to send it back to the server to implement the JWT auth circle.
Since httpOnly cookies are not accesible via JavaScript, i read that i have to just set the withCredentials option to true in order to send the cookie back to the server.
But as you can see i have set the credentials to true, also have the sameSite set to none but i cant access the token in the server.
I updated the question with screenshots , you can take a look.

sameSite: "None" NOT sameSite: "none"

Yes, i tried with 'None' too , but nothing changed.
You can see the latest screenshot of the response
